# Ubuntu help with wired connection

Tags: networking, vmware, wired

Well, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 [Desktop] on VMware Workstation 1.0.0, and when I open Firefox, it can't connect to the internet because the wired connection isn't connected, but on my Windows 8.1 computer [the one with VMware Workstation on] it has a wired connection already connected and it's working fine, on Ubuntu it doesn't. Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your network is set to NAT in VMware and is Also connected at power on. Also that is an old version can you upgrade your workstation?

[image]

Comment: I'll just uninstall VMware Workstation and install VMware Player.